# Is it possible to mix Scala and Kotlin in the same maven module?

Tags: java, scala, maven, kotlin

I am working with Kotlin configured by maven as explained here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-maven.html#compiling-kotlin-and-java-sources (but using only java src dir for both Java and Kotlin files).
We have at work some Scala modules that are configured as explained here: https://dzone.com/articles/scala-in-java-maven-project.

The obvious way of put both maven plugins together did not work. Scala did not recognize Kotlin files.

Is it possible to mix both Java, Kotlin and Scala in one maven module? or is there is a conflict in those maven plugins?

Comment: Probably won't help you, but I have an example of a Gradle project that uses Java, Kotlin, Groovy and Ceylon in the same project: https://github.com/renatoathaydes/ceylon-gradle-plugin/tree/master/ceylon-gradle-plugin-tests/cross-language-modules.

If you can't get that working in Maven, maybe try Gradle :D

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately, I need it for work, and we use maven.

Comment: If you want to make this work, separate the Kotlin and Scala code into  modules that compile separately otherwise it'll be impossible to know what to compile first. With the modules separate, one will be able to depend on the other, but not both depend on each other. So it should work without issue.